# If you want to end the conversation politely, how do you say it?

Tags: expression-choice

If you want to end the conversation politely, especially when you are aware others are busy, what do you say? Something like:

> *I will leave you alone?*

Is there any better way to say that?

Comment: Say "Okay, thank you, See you" and nod your head. "I will leave you alone" is unfriendly, implying that the other wants you to go, preferring to be alone than to be with you. If true, keep it to yourself.

Comment: Depends on you, your interlocutors, and the context. The question is unclear or too broad.

Comment: Are you talking about face to face communication, or on the telephone?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, indeed. The important word there being *ok* -  which is understood as a discourse marker signalling the end of the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

"I will let you go now, I know you're busy."

"I'll let you get back to what you were doing now. Thank you for talking with me!"

"Thanks for taking the time to talk with me, I'll let you get back to work now."

"Wow! We've been talking for 20 minutes. I've got to run, thanks so much for the chat!"

Comment: While these are all polite offerings, I get resistance when I imply that _you_ are too busy for me (even if you are, and also gave me that impression). I vote for the last choice here, which makes no mention of being busy.

Comment: +1 for *I'll let you...* It's idiomatic and the hearer should recognize that the speaker is signaling that he wishes to terminate the conversation.

Comment: "I'd like to continue our chat, but I just remembered that I left the nuclear football in Air Force 1, so I have to bolt."